# SharedPreferences String name

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have been working on an app that scores teams based on how well they do in certain criteria, and I want it to save the teams data. So if the app closes, it doesn't lose their data.
Here is my save Class

```
package com.example.elliott.alliancepicker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.example.elliott.alliancepicker.MainActivity;
import com.example.elliott.alliancepicker.Question;
import com.example.elliott.alliancepicker.Team;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Save {
    String[] TeamBaseData = null;
    String[] TeamSplitData = new String[11];
    int[] TeamScoreData = new int[9];
    private static String prefsFileName = "prefs";
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    String compileSave = "";
    public Save(Context context) {
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(prefsFileName,     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public void SaveTeamScore(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(prefsFileName, compileSave);
    editor.apply();
}
public Team regenTeam(){
    String toSplit = "";
    int questionScore = 0;
    TeamBaseData = (compileSave.split("@"));
    for (int i = 0; i < TeamBaseData.length; i++){
        toSplit = TeamBaseData[i];
        TeamSplitData = toSplit.split("%");
        for (int e = 2; e < TeamSplitData.length; e++) {
            int x = 0;
            toSplit = TeamSplitData[i];
            questionScore = Integer.parseInt(toSplit);
            TeamScoreData[x] = questionScore;
            x++;
        }
        if (TeamSplitData.length != 1) {
            Team newTeam = new Team(TeamSplitData[0], TeamSplitData[1], TeamScoreData);
            return newTeam;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    return prefs;
}

public void setCompileSave(String compileSave) {
    this.compileSave = this.compileSave + compileSave;
}
}
```

Unfortunately... Every time I try to run my code it crashes
and here is my exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elliott.alliancepicker/com.example.elliott.alliancepicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:169)
        at com.example.elliott.alliancepicker.Save.<init>(Save.java:24)
```

**Thank you all for helping me solve my problem!**

Comment: how are you instantiating the Save class ?

Comment: make sure the context you are passing isn't null

Comment: Yes you should check if context isn't null  and then create the object. Where are you creating the Save object ?

Comment: I initiate the save as Save save = new Save(this); Should I do if (context != null) { Save save = new Save(this);}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your context passed to `new Save()` an Application context? Try changing it to Activity.

I.e. replace `new Save(getApplicationContext())` with `new Save(this)` if your are in an `Activity` class, or replace with `new Save(getActivity())` if you use it in `Fragment` class.

Comment: I am doing new Save(this), should I try using new Save(getApplicationContext());?

Comment: Do you call new Save(this) in onCreate? If not move it there

Answer (score 0):

try to create your object on the main thread

```
Handler mainHandler = new         Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new      Runnable() {
@Override 
    public void run() {....} // This is your    code
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

Comment: I have to get my data to save from one class, and I show my data in MainActivity. So I don't know how I would set it up to do that

Comment: when saving the data.. instead of save put this code.. and put the save code inside method run... in other words.. run the same save commands.. but inside run method..

Comment: Do I put the run in my MainActivity, where I will need to read the saved data to display? or put it in my other class, where I get my data. Thank you so much for your help by the way!

Comment: the point is... that if the code that saves or reads data is running on another thread... you will need to use  this code..

Comment: if the code is running in oncreate in the main activity... no need to  do that...